# Change chromium duplicate save file naming

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

When I save a duplicate file in chromium, the name gets set to `"<filename> (<num>)"`. Is it possible to change this to `"<filename>_<num>"` somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Chromium source code, looks like the bit that puts parenthesis around the dup number is at line 516, of chromium/src/chrome/browser/resources/file_manager/js/util.js:

```
    trialPath = prefix + ' (' + copyNumber + ')' + ext;
```

Soooo, unless you wish to recompile your browser, I'd say no.

BUT, if you were handy with a hex-editor (remember those?), you could change the strings ' (' and ')' to the appropriate values to create your _ filename.

I looked, there's many (many!) instances of ' (', ')' groups in the 94 meg chrome app on my linux box.  I won't be teasing you with a list of offsets. Apologies.

Y'know, there might be an extension or app that could do that though, like a post-download filename fixer or something.  Or you could write one.